# Why *should* we use EventHandler

Tags: c#, generics, event-handling

I hate EventHandler. I hate that I have to cast the `sender` if I want to do anything with it. I hate that I have to make a new class inheriting from `EventArgs` to use `EventHandler<T>`.

I've always been told that `EventHandler` is the tradition and blah, blah...whatever. But I can't find a reason why this dogma is still around.

Is there a reason why it would be a bad idea to make a new delegate:

```
delegate void EventHandler<TSender, T>(TSender sender, T args);
```

That way the `sender` will be typesafe and I can pass whatever the heck I want as the arguments (including custom EventArgs if I so desire).

Comment: Then you may aswell just use Action<TSender, TArgs> as your delegate.

Comment: Yea very true, so I'll extend my question : why not use Action<TSender, TArgs> ?

Comment: Events and Callbacks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/events-and-callbacks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There actually is a good reason for requiring the second argument to derive from `EventArgs` if your fully-trusted code hosts third-party code as partially-trusted.

Because the callback to the event handling delegate is done in the context of the raising code and not the third party code, it is possible for malicious third-party code to add a privileged system operation as an event handler and thus potentially execute an escalation of privilege attack by running code in your fully-trusted context that their partially-trusted context could not run.

For example, if you declare a handler as type `int -> void` then the third-party code could enqueue `YourEvent += Enviroment.Exit(-1)` and have you exit the process unintentionally. This would obviously cause an easy-to-detect problem, but there are far more malicious APIs that could be enqueued to do other things.

When the signature is `(object, EventArgs) -> void` then there are no privileged operations in the framework that can be enqueued because none of them are compatible with this signature. It's part of the security code review in the framework to ensure this (unfortunately I cannot find the source where I read this).

So in certain circumstances there are valid security concerns as to why you should use the standard pattern. If you're 100% sure your code will never be used in these circumstances then the event signature guideline isn't as important (apart from other developers thinking WTF), but if it might be then you should follow it.

Comment: +1 Wow.  Nice post. This is the type of posts that keep me coming back to SO.

Comment: Very very interesting. I love to know if this was in the original design or convention fell out or usage.

Comment: Though this is a valid answer with the current state of affairs, it seems it would be much better if code that shouldn't call Exit (or pass it through to be called) wasn't even be able to access Exit in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand one thing. With `EventHandler` you can't do `YourEvent += EnvironmentExit`, but how about `YourEvent += (sender, args) => Environment.Exit(-1)`? Isn't that the same and `Exit` will be called in fully-trusted context?

Comment: i want ask the same question)
we can simply wrap Enviroment.Exit(-1) to MyEventHandler..

Comment: Does @prostynick comment invalidate this response?  Are we back to square one - there's not a good reason except convention?

Comment: This is just wrong... as @prostynick said, you can register any callback anyways. Why does this have so many upvotes?

Comment: I think it strongly needs citation. I think it is not the place to pursue security. This is the reason of my downvote.

Comment: -1 There may be reasons for it, but this answer definitely doesn't make sense (as pointed out above). Could you chime in @Greg? If not, it may be best to retract this answer, as I'm certain your intent wasn't to spread misinformation.

Answer (score 10):

There is no reason to use it other than **its the accepted .net convention** and anyone reading your code should understand it fairly easily. For this it's a good reason.

However it's your code and you can decide what best for you. Of course as you interact with the fcl you will have to do it their way using event handlers.

Comment: That being said, a strongly typed delegate would also be recognised :)

Comment: I don't see why developers would be confused by the OP's code.  However, +1 for pointing out the obvious: it's his code to do with as he will.

Answer (score 7):

I commonly use `Action<...>` types as event handlers - if you don't need to interop with other code (or a designer) that specifically requires `EventHandler`, there's no reason to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you, the convention is stupid and/or antiquated.  Do it the right way, with proper type safety and generics.

It comes up all the time that you have a task to do, and you can follow the way the last guy did it OR do it another way that you think is probably better.

The first choice is usually chosen -- do it the same as the last guy, and you won't get in trouble.  But the second choice is what improves software over the long haul.  (Or at least it CAN improve it, if you're right that your way is better! :) )

Answer (score 2):

Well, doing all that casting is unusual, the client code quite often already knows who the *sender* is because it explicitly subscribed the event for only one object.  Sharing event handlers is fairly rare.  If common behavior is desirable then the better approach is to derive from the class and override the OnXxxx method.  You then no longer care about *sender*, you got *this*.

But, solve your problem trivially by including a type-safe reference to the sender in your custom EventArgs derived class.

Comment: i don't agree with you.
for example client code can have only one handler on array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As Preet Sangha said, the reason why creating such a delegate would be a bad idea is that other developers could be confused why you doing it in that way.

Using `EventHandler` delegate is a guideline presented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx

Comment: You might argue, though, that if using, say, `Action<...>` as your event handler is enough to confuse a team member, your team has bigger problems already. ;)

Comment: I've been programming for 20 years, the last 10 years in C# and it would confuse me, but then the goal of most advanced shops today seems to be to use the most complicated designs possible, not to use simple approaches.

Comment: 6 years passed since I posted that answer and I totally stay by my statement. There's a lot of inexperienced developers around, some developers that switched languages, some that are still juniors, but they're still needed in projects and so on, so when you take an average developer you don't always end up with the most brightest people on earth. Surely it's best to work in a company that only hires the crème de la crème, but in reality it's better to expect someone might get confused by things like that. Even experienced people might. And the ultimate goal should be the readiness of code.

Comment: i just want to add my 2 cents from my personal view point at this moment:
i just started working with C# like 2 months ago, so i'd count myself as one of the "inexperienced developers" you were referring to.
And for me the fact that some code uses `EventHandler` where some other simpler delegate type like `Action` would be fine made me google this SO-Question. Because when I see `EventHandler` being used I assume that it's done for a specific purpose.

Comment: Note that this has been asked more than 11 years go. And yes, you might be confused why someone is not using Action. Those EventHandlers where popular with WinForms back then