# I am new to delegates and wonder how to break down the following code

Tags: c#

I have the following code and am wondering how to break it down?  It works great but was written by a guru and is over my head.  Thank you in advance for any help.

The code basically writes device information sent and received to the GUI.  It seems like it has events created based on the device and also invokes GUI stuff.

1. Why would you need to invoke?
2. I guess I'm wondering if this is overly complicated or appropriate?  What may be a better way to accomplish the same task?
3. I'm also wondering what the "delegate { };" does?

> public event EventHandler CommunicationPerformed = delegate { };

```
    SerialPort _port;
    readonly int _delay = 100;


    private string ReadAndUpdateStatus()
    {
        string read = _port.ReadExisting();
        CommunicationPerformed?.Invoke(this, new LoaderReadWriteEventArgs(read, LoaderCommunicationDirection.Read));
        return read;
    }

    private void WriteAndUpdateStatus(string data)
    {
        if (!data.StartsWith("//")) //ignore "Comment" lines but show them on the GUI to read
            _port.Write(data);
        CommunicationPerformed?.Invoke(this, new LoaderReadWriteEventArgs(data, LoaderCommunicationDirection.Write));
    }



public class LoaderReadWriteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public LoaderCommunicationDirection Direction { get; }

    public string Value { get; }

    public LoaderReadWriteEventArgs(string value, LoaderCommunicationDirection direction)
    {
        Value = value;
        Direction = direction;
    }
}

public enum LoaderCommunicationDirection
{
    Read,
    Write
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You asked three questions, and as usual, only one of them got answered. Try to ask only one question in your question.

> I'm also wondering what the `delegate { }` does?
>
> ```
>   public event EventHandler CommunicationPerformed = delegate { };
> ```

As the other answer notes, events are null by default in C#.  This technique makes an event handler that does *nothing*, but is not *null*.

There are, unfortunately, many syntaxes for an anonymous function in C#.  `delegate {}` means "give me a do-nothing function that matches any non-ref-out formal parameter list that is void returning". That's why people do `delegate{}`, because it works almost anywhere in a context where an event handler is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to review this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/.

> Why would you need to invoke?

*To broadcast to event handlers (any party who registered for this event get notified this way)*

> I guess I'm wondering if this is overly complicated or appropriate?
>
> *What may be a better way to accomplish the same task?

This is not complicated. This is pretty much as easy as it gets.*

> I'm also wondering what the "delegate { };" does?

my two cents. 
I dont know which code line you are refering but a delegate is a type that holds a reference to a method. A delegate is declared with a signature that shows the return type and parameters for the methods it references, and can hold references only to methods that match its signature. A delegate is thus equivalent to a type-safe function pointer or a callback. A delegate declaration is sufficient to define a delegate class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try to answer #1 and #2 (3 is already covered).

#1 - At some point, someone decided that other parts of the program could subscribe to an event that tells them when communication has been performed.  Once that decision has been made, it's kind of a "contract".  You perform the communication->you fire the event that notifies subscribers that communication has been performed.  What those subscribers are doing about that, or why they need to know...Actually not really any of your concern if this class is your focus.  In theory, at least.  And often that's really practically the case.  If your class is doing its job, it's not really your concern who is listening to the events.

#2 - I **do** think the method of declaring events and event handlers in your code is overly complicated.  Plenty of people (and official [Microsoft best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/event)) disagree with me.  You can google "why should my event handlers use eventargs" and read plenty on the subject.  [Or Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880789/why-should-we-use-eventhandler).  Another approach is the following:

```
public event Action<string, LoaderCommunicationDirection> CommunicationPerformed;
void PerformWrite()
{
  string myComm = "String I'm sending";
  //Line of code that performs communication that writes string here
  CommunicationPerformed?.Invoke(myComm, LoaderCommunicationDirection.Write);
}
```

This is much more succinct than having an entire class that derives from `EventArgs`.  However, it has the very obvious drawback that if you are an event subscriber...you have no idea what `string` is.  Of course, since it's named `value` in your code...that's not much more helpful.  And a comment above the event declaration is just about as useful.

Answer (score 1):

orhtej2 answered your first question quite nicely. Using the explicit Invoke method allows you to leverage the null conditional operator, which reduces the code to fire the event a single line.

As for whether this is overly complicated: No, that's basically how events are done.

What I've sometimes seen (especially in combination with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in MVVM patterns) are helper methods, which encapsulate the longer, but more obvious pre-C#6 code and let you fire the event with less plumbing.

```
private void FireCommPerformed(string value, LoaderCommunicationDirection direction) 
{ 
    EventHandler handler = CommunicationPerformed;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new LoaderReadWriteEventArgs(value, direction)));
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
private string ReadAndUpdateStatus()
{
    string read = _port.ReadExisting();
    FireCommPerformed(read, LoaderCommunicationDirection.Read);
    return read;
}
```

The Delegate { } is simply an empty delegate, like a null for events. Unless some other method in the code subscribes to the CommunicationPerformed event of this class during runtime, nothing will happen when the event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus in on what is exactly happening here. This should help you figure out everything else.

```
CommunicationPerformed?.Invoke(this, new LoaderReadWriteEventArgs(read, LoaderCommunicationDirection.Read));
```

This is checking to see if the delegate (event handlers are delegates) (CommunicationPerformed) is null.

Delegates are pointers (but with extra functionality).

If the delegate (pointer) is null, it means that nothing has been assigned to it.

Pointers store memory locations. In this case, it makes a memory reference to the function 'this'. 'This' is a reference to ReadAndUpdateStatus().

So this line basically says: "since the pointer is null, have this pointer reference the ReadAndUpdateStatus() function".

But what about the event args? Well... This is where delegates diverge from pointers.

Delegates don't just safely hold and store memory locations. They also can hold parameters.

You use a class that extends from EventArgs as the way of passing in a list of parameters.

From here, the event handler (event handlers are delegates) CommunicationPerformed will coordinate sending that list of arguments to whatever functions require it.

These functions are called whenever CommunicationPerformed is invoked (e.g. told to run). This is typically indicated with a:

```
+=CommunicationPerformed(foo,bar)
```

Now - why would use event handlers (or any delegate - for that matter)?

They're verbose and annoying to read (way more work than writing a simple bool and a trigger function), they don't look like other function, and they're frankly weird - right?

Except that they're really useful. Here's how:

1.) They work a lot like Tasks. You can invoke them in Parallel, in loops, wherever. They keep consistent state. They don't "bleed" and cause bugs.

2.) They're pointers. Guaranteed pass-by-reference. Except, they're magical, and if you stop using the delegate, they won't linger in memory.

3.) They allow you to control state in loops. Sometimes, a bool trigger won't work properly if you're in a really tight loop. You fire an event? Guaranteed behavior that your trigger will only be fired once.